# Изменение расстояния между ячейками UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

У меня есть `collectionView` и в нем статичное количество ячеек, выглядит вот так:

### [image: collectionView]

Я хотел бы узнать, как уменьшить расстояние между ячейками, обозначенное красными стрелками на рисунке. Изменение параметров `min spacing for cells` и `min spacing for lines` не помогло
Использую стандартный collectionViewFlowLayout.

**UPDATE**

### [image: cell]

Сам collection view находится в ячейке table view и для него констрейнты установлены верно. `min spacing for lines` работает только в сторону увеличения расстояния (из-за чего ячейки выстраиваются в ряд). Хотелось бы оставить такое расположение ячеек, но уменьшить расстояние между ними.

Возможно, стоит добавить, что большая ячейка находится в отдельной секции от маленьких.

**UPDATE 2**
Попробовал покрасить ячейки и менять interitem spacing

.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

### [image: spacing 0]

.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20

### [image: spacing 20]

.minimumInteritemSpacing = 100

### [image: spacing 100]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, которое подошло мне: я изменил размеры самого `collectionView`, чтобы ячейки прижались ближе друг к другу.

Другие возможные варианты решений:

1. Реализовать `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` и в нем реализовать методы: `sectionInsets`, `itemsPerRow`, `interItemSpace`.
2. Писать свой сабклас от UICollectionViewFlowLayout и вводить параметр вроде "maxInteritemSpace".

Помочь подробнее могут ответы на этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

1. Для этого используется Min Spacing For Lines. Убедитесь, что вы установили констрейнты для самого Collection View, например, в границах экрана. Чтобы autolayout мог сработать
2. Установите констрейнты Equal Width и Equal Height кнопки относительно Cell и укажите нужный multiplier (например, 0.2)

Comment: Констрейнты для самого Collection View установлены. Этот коллекшн находится в ячейке tableView и констрейнты для него корректны (с виду).
Min Spacing For Lines не помогает даже если увести его в 0, но вот в другую сторону работает.

С кнопкой все верно, но я немного не того результата ожидал. В случае с констрейнтами кнопка будет изменяться пропорционально, и, как кажется, мне они не подходят.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, для кнопки Вы можете оставить один констрейнт, например, ширину и установить Aspect Ratio 1:1

Comment: Min Spacing For Lines работает, но, возможно, у Вас размер ячейки такой, что кажется, что ничего не меняется. Покрасьте всю ячейку (background color), чтобы посмотреть расстояние между ними.

Comment: Добавил в исходный пост скриншоты с изменением min spacing и покрашенными ячейками.
Забыл написать в самом начале, что UICollectionViewFlowLayout стандартный, не менял и не наследовал.

Может для подобного результата необходимо писать кастомный Layout?

Comment: Уберите секцию с большой ячейкой, по-экспериментируйте с маленькими.

Comment: При увеличении высоты маленьких ячеек они становятся ближе друг к другу по высоте, но тогда они перестают влезать без скролла :/